# GCP inter-project IAM with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

I'm new to GCP and terraform, i need some explanation about the topic in the title.

My problem:
I have 2 (or more) GCP projects under the same organization.
I want a cloud run from project A to write on a bucket in project B.
I have two terraform projects, one for each GCP project.
My question is: how can I make things work?

Thanks in advance.

I created the bucket in project B.
I created the cloud run in project A.

I created a service account in project A for the cloudrun.
In project B I created the binding, but something is not clear to me...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! To help answer, it would be great if you could include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your Terraform code, which exhibits the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Cloud Run should have an attached service account. That service account needs and IAM role granting access to the storage bucket in Project B. Go the Project B's IAM and add the service account email address with the required IAM role. Edit your question with details on your HCL, what you have configured for Cloud Run, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your project's B terraform:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "grant_access_to_sa_from_project_a_to_this_bucket" {
  provider = google

  bucket = "<my_project_b_bucket_name"
  role   = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
  member = "serviceAccount:my_service_account@project_a.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Specify the role according to what you need. The list of the gcs roles are [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).
The docs of gcs buckets IAM policies are [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket_iam).